# Spring + Vue , response setHeader "index.html"

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vue.js, server

Do you know how to set the response setHeader to a static file?

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                    Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                    return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: dont ask question like this: "do you know"... asking question that you need help for fixing your bug or error.